# I'm searching for a good tool to publish and share markdown files

Tags: markdown

I've been a user of [Workflowy](https://workflowy.com/) since a lot of time.

As a teacher, it has been a great tool to

- note ideas for my courses,
- share some parts of my lists to my students, including links and videos
- filter notes by tags

Workflowy doesn't evolve anymore, and I'm looking for a better tool.

I've started using the opensource [logseq](https://logseq.com/), which is very nice to use; but lacks an essential thing:
The ability to publish (& share) content easily.

I'm wondering if someone has a suggestion for this.

I would rather prefer a free solution (or at least, with reasonable fees) : [Obsidian](https://obsidian.md/pricing), for example, charges about 16$ a month for sync + publish: that is too much for me.

I've also been interested in [Docsify⁠–⁠This](https://docsify-this.net/#/); whose concept is good : it justs parses a mardown file URL and renders it on the fly.  Which means that it's easy to maintain.
Problem is that it doesn't load medias (like Youtube) nor has tags.

Does someone has a suggestion ?

Thanks!